# cannot make publicly visible class from internal class?

Tags: c#

I have an internal class:

```
internal abstract class Reader
{
    //internal abstract void methods
}
```

I cannot make this class:

```
public abstract class CustomFileReader : Reader
{
}
```

Because it is more visible than the class it inherits from.  I want to do this to enforce that you must inherit from a publicly accessible inheritor of the Reader class and not the base class.  Is this possible or do I have to expose the base class?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't have an `internal` class in the inheritance tree of a `public` class, but you *can* force users to derive from `CustomFileReader` instead of `Reader`, by making the only constructor of `Reader` internal:

```
public abstract class Reader
{
    internal Reader()
    {
    }
}

public abstract class CustomFileReader : Reader
{
    // Public and protected constructors here
}
```

Now anything which tries to inherit directly from `Reader` outside your assembly will be told that it can't find an accessible base class constructor.